# Is it possible to install Office 2016 on a Windows 10 tablet PC with a 10.1 inch screen?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, microsoft-word, office365, microsoft-office-2016

I recently obtained an ASUS Transformer Mini, which is characterised as a 2-in-1 laptop and tablet PC, runs Windows 10, and which I mainly intended to use for creating and editing Microsoft Word documents.

The tablet ships with Microsoft Office Mobile; however, because it has a screen size of exactly 10.1 inches, it seems that the [version of Office Mobile that it ships with allows for reading, but not creating or editing Word documents](https://www.extremetech.com/mobile/211374-is-microsoft-office-mobile-free-for-tablets-it-depends) (only devices with a screen size of less than 10.1 inches have editing capabilities).

My research so far has led me to believe that Office Mobile and Office 365 are the only versions of Microsoft Office that can run on tablet devices, and that the desktop Office 2016 suite is incompatible with my device even though my device also functions as a PC. At best, the information out there on this is confusing.

I already have the desktop media for Office 2016 at hand. Can I simply load this media onto a USB drive to install the Office 2016 suite to my tablet, or will my only option be to subscribe to and use the cloud-based Office 365 suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you haven't used up all of your licensed installs for the Office 2016, you should have no problem with installing it on the tablet; the tablet's processor is the Atom, not ARM, and will support Windows 10 Pro (and upgrading from Home to Pro is recommended by Asus) and standard Windows desktop applications.

Office Mobile is designed for iOS and Android devices, and will permit editing of documents on such devices if the user has a Microsoft account and logs thereinto. The account and the use of the service is free if the iOS or Android device is smaller than 10 inches; you will need a subscription to Office 365 for iOS or Android devices using Office Mobile that are 10.1 inches or larger. Since you are using Windows 10 on a "desktop" processor, the Office Mobile restrictions do not apply; you should treat your device as a "standard" desktop or laptop for this purpose.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer that goes into detail about processor type, it hadn't occurred to me that the distinction that separates 2-in-1s from true mobile devices is in the processor. It's also the only answer technically correct about Office Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  The ASUS Transformer Mini is a full PC with the capability of running Microsoft Office, as well as any other Windows software.  It is not the most powerful machine, but is more than capable of handling MS office.  To answer your second question,  you can copy the installation media to a USB drive and install it that way.

FYI, Office Mobile is simply a "convenience" application.  It only allows for viewing Office documents.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/4026853/office-office-2016-system-requirements), Office 2016 will run on:

> Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows
>   10 Server, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, or Windows
>   Server 2008 R2. For the best experience, use the latest version of any
>   operating system.

So if you device also works as a PC, you will be able to install it just fine. It just won't be optimized for touch and smaller screens.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, definitely if the tablet is windows yes, but if windows exp probably not your gonna have to crack it (Not literally) But just search up an apk for office 2016 and it will pop up, be sure to include your system details but not personal ones ;)

Comment: 'apk' is an Android thing, not a Windows thing. The Desktop version of Office 2016 should install on the indicated tablet, as it uses an Intel Atom, rather than an ARM.